# Is there a smart way to validate function input in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, validation

I'm writing a simple DiceRoller application and I've created the primary function, however I'm wondering if there is a "smart" way to validate function inputs in Clojure rather than using branching conditionals to validate input? My function is below with a sample test, I would have to also test if n is not a number with another if or an or and it feels messy.

Also if anyone can point out a smarter way to do this function I would appreciate any feedback, this is my first attempt at trying to program functionally

```
(ns DiceRoller)

(defn roll
"rolls a specified number of n sided dice "
([] (roll 1 6))
([number] (roll number 6))
([number n]
  (if-not number? number (throw (IllegalArgumentException. (str "incorrect input, integers only"))))
  (take number (repeatedly #(+ (rand-int n) 1)))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mostly the Clojure attitude is "just assume you got the right thing". In this case, if you took out your check entirely, the user would get basically the same exception eventually. But if you really wanted to do this, you should do it correctly! Right now your code throws an exception on every input, because you're missing parens around `(number? number)`.

Comment: Thanks I just threw it in as an example when I was posting this, didn't actually debug or anything. I would have assumed it would be better to fail gracefully, does closure have built-in catch block functionality?

Comment: What's more graceful about throwing your custom exception rather than the "automatic" exception when `repeatedly` notices that `number` isn't a number?

Comment: @amalloy it gives you a chance to provide a more meaningful error message. this can be much nicer for users than expecting them to decode whatever exception repeatedly throws.

Comment: "just assume you got the right thing" is contrary to the notion of defensive programming.

Comment: attitude aside, the other answer here shows the idiomatic way of performing input verifications, and this _is useful_ in many cases

Answer (score 25):

Sure there is - you can use a `:pre` assertion for that.

```
(defn some-fun [x]
  {:pre [(number? x)]}
  (foo x))
```

Now you'll get *AssertionError Assert failed: (number? x)* if you pass the function a non-numeric argument `x`.

Checking whether the input is a number is kind of useless as @amalloy already pointed out, but there are lots of totally valid precondition (and postcondition for that matter) checks that you might want to apply to your function. You can see some more details on the subject [here](http://objectcommando.com/blog/2010/03/07/design-by-contract-with-clojure/) and [here](http://blog.fogus.me/2009/12/21/clojures-pre-and-post/).

Comment: I like this, but isn't it "yucky" to have to use try-catch when you call the function? Feels too much like Java.